# Calling a function pointer passed to another function

Tags: c, function-pointers

So I can't seem to get this simple function pointer to run without seg faulting

Here is what I am working with:

test.c:

```
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 typedef void (*lwpfun)(void *);     
 static void indentnum(void * num);

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    lwp_create((lwpfun)indentnum,(void*)42); 

    return 0;
 }

 static void indentnum(void *num) {
    printf("Indent num: %d\n", *(int *)num);
 }
```

lwp.c

```
 #include "stdio.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void lwp_create( void (*lwpfun)(void *), void *arg){
    (*lwpfun)(arg); //Seg faulting
 }
```

Comment: Assigning literals to pointers is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Why are you casting the first argument to `lwp_create()`? Why all those casts at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lwp_create((lwpfun)indentnum,(void*)42);
```

No need to cast here, but you should take the *address* of your function to make it a *function pointer* (logical, isn't it?)

```
lwp_create(&indentnum,(void*)42);
```

(it WILL work without address of operator, this is just for clarity)

Next problem here:

```
 static void indentnum(void *num) {
    printf("Indent num: %d\n", *(int *)num);
 }
```

If you really want an `int` casted to a `void *` passed in here, that doesn't make it magically a pointer -- so just cast back to `int` (`(int) num`). dereferencing it will of course crash, why should `42` be a valid pointer?

Then here:

```
 void lwp_create( void (*lwpfun)(void *), void *arg){
    (*lwpfun)(arg); //Seg faulting
 }
```

The argument should have the *type* `lwpfun` (you made that `typedef` for a reason, right?) ... you can call it just like you call a regular function. So try this:

```
 void lwp_create(lwpfun callback, void *arg){
    callback(arg);
 }
```

Comment: This works like a charm, giving you the accepted answer. Mucho Gracias!

Comment: @EmmettHarper you're welcome. I suggest you consider the other answers, too, because they focus on the really critical problem you were facing here: Keep in mind casting an `int` to a pointer is not universally portable, although it works on *most* platforms.

Comment: Using the name of a function implicitly decays to a pointer; `indentnum` is exactly the same as `&indentnum` (and also `*indentnum` and `*******************indentnum`)

Comment: @M.M I already said it's for clarity (convention: take a pointer) and NOT a necessity.

Answer (score 2):

You’re passing `num` as `(void*)42`, which is a garbage pointer, then casting and dereferencing it.  Either pass the address of an `int` variable or (less portably) cast it back to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
lwp_create((lwpfun)indentnum,(void*)42);
```

to:

```
lwp_create(indentnum, &(int []){42});  // use of a C99 compound literal
```

or in C89:

```
int x = 42;
lwp_create(indentnum, &x);
```

Your first form does not a pass a pointer to an object with the `int` value `42` but a pointer formed with the conversion of `42` to a pointer value.

Comment: This doesn't work seem to work, but the way I originally had it works fine. I'm sorry but I don't think this is right at all

Comment: @EmmettHarper it has been tested and works fine on my system.